# How to print a certain amount of characters of a number in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a percentage finder, pretty basic. But, I would only like to print 4 characters in the float or int. Can anyone help?
Here is my code so far:

```
    numer = int(input("What's the numerator?"))
    denom = int(input("What's the denominator?"))
    percent = (numer / denom * 100, "%")
    print(percent)
```

I want the output for 5/6 to be:

```
    83.33%
```

But it actually prints:

```
    83.33333333333334%
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use % in print function

```
print("%.2f"%(a/b))
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked!